# Indicator for currently applied Firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm working with Firebase's Cloud Firestore and I'm implementing some security rules.

As I'm continuously changing them, I'd like to know if there is a way to know which ruleset is currently active.

I know the Console suggests waiting for a few minutes before the new rules replace the old ones, but there is no way to know when they are safe to test.

I could wait a set amount of time (potentially wasting time) or even rewrite correct rules because they weren't active yet when I tested them.

How do I go about solving this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no way to know whether your new rules have been deployed yet. Sorry about that. I just mostly test for my changes to become active with some minimal code that I wrote to test the change anyway. It usually doesn't take nearly as long as the few minutes that the console warns about btw.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm using a random boolean variable that I toggle each time I change some rules, so based on the result of that test I can tell if the rules already changed or not.
And I agree, it isn't that much of a problem, I was just wondering if there actually was a better way not to overthink this.
Also I love what you do! Have a good day.